# What will array_column return if a key name doesn't exist?

Tags: php, associative-array

According to https://wiki.php.net/rfc/array_column array_column is slated to be added to PHP soon. But I having trouble understanding the RFC. What will be returned if a named key doesn't exist?

**Example:**

```
$arr = array(
    array(
        'firstname' => 'Bob',
        'lastname'  => 'Tomato'
    ),
    array(
        'firstname' => 'Larry',
        'lastname'  => 'Cucumber'
    )
);

$middlenames = array_column($arr, 'middlename');
```

Comment: what is this function array_column?

Comment: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/array_column

Comment: Looking at the RFC, it doesn't seem to say what would happen in this scenario.  My guess is it would return an empty array.

Comment: [*There is a test case for this*](https://github.com/ramsey/php-src/blob/3439a098a0/ext/standard/tests/array/array_column_basic.phpt#L93) — The answer is, an empty array.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Introduction**

For you to understand the RFC you need to understand the problem first and the reason it was introduced.

**Your Array**

```
$arr = array(
        array(
                'firstname' => 'Bob',    <--
                'lastname' => 'Tomato'     |    <--
        ),                                 |      |
        array(                             |      |
                'firstname' => 'Larry',  <--      |
                'lastname' => 'Cucumber'        <-|
        )
);
```

**Getting Column**

To get `Bob & Larry` or `Tomato and Cucumber` you have use more than one line of code examples are :

```
$colums = array();
foreach ( array_map(null, $arr[0], $arr[1]) as $value ) {
    $colums[] = $value;
}
print_r($colums);
```

[Output](http://eval.in/14899)

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Bob
            [1] => Larry
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Tomato
            [1] => Cucumber
        )

)
```

**Dynamic Version**

The code above would only work if you know number of elements another creative way would be

```
$colums = array();
array_unshift($arr, null);
foreach (call_user_func_array("array_map", $arr) as $value ) {
    $colums[] = $value;
}
```

[Live Test](http://eval.in/14900)

Or better still, use `MultipleIterator`

```
$mi = new MultipleIterator(MultipleIterator::MIT_NEED_ALL);
foreach ( $arr as $v ) {
    $mi->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($v));
}

$colums = array();
foreach ( $mi as $v ) {
    $colums[] = $v;
}
print_r($colums);
```

[Live Test](http://eval.in/14901)

**Key Name**

If you need to get the key name here is another method

```
$colums = array_reduce($arr, function ($a, $b) {
    foreach ( $b as $k => $v ) {
        $a[$k][] = $v;
    }
    return $a;
});
```

[Live Test](http://eval.in/14898)

**Back to `array_column`**

`array_column` intends simply the process and getting all columns with first name would be as simple as the following:

```
 print_r(array_column($arr,"lastname"));
                               ^
                               |
                               +--- This get value with key "lastname"
```

[Live Test](http://3v4l.org/Jh3eQ)

**More Complex Senerio**

Imagine you want your array to have this output

```
Array
(
    [Bob] => Tomato
    [Larry] => Cucumber
)
```

Use Old methods you can have

```
$colums = array();
array_unshift($arr, null);
foreach (call_user_func_array("array_map", $arr) as $value ) {
    $key = array_shift($value);
    $colums[$key] = current($value);
}
print_r($colums);
```

[Live Test](http://eval.in/14902)

Now you can see I had to use `array_shift` and `current` to get the first two elements. As your array grows, this can become complex, but `array_column` would simplify this:

```
print_r(array_column($arr,"lastname","firstname"));
                              ^           ^
                              |           |
                             Value       Key    (I wonder why position is backwards)
```

[Output](http://3v4l.org/13sTu)

```
Array
(
    [Bob] => Tomato
    [Larry] => Cucumber
)
```

**Finally Back to your Question**

> What will be returned if a named key doesn't exist?

Empty array from your example

```
 print_r(array_column($arr,"middlename"));
                                ^
                                |
                        it would try to check if any of your array has key middle man
```

[It returns](http://3v4l.org/DRdgT)

```
Array        <------- Otherwise returns empty array 
(
)
```

**Conclusion**

I used so many different examples using `loop`, `array_map`, `array_reduce`, and `MultipleIterator` to explain what `array_column` is trying to achieve.

As you can see `array_column` is much more simplified, but [I would advise you play with the examples in the RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/array_column) a little and this would allow you understand it better if you still don't understand it. PHP is a flexible language you can always implement your own version.

Answer (score 5):

As per: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/array_column

> When a corresponding indexKey cannot be found, the value will be keyed with an integer, starting from zero.

Example used in RFC:

```
$mismatchedColumns = array(
   array(
       'a' => 'foo',
       'b' => 'bar',
       'e' => 'baz'
   ),
   array(
       'a' => 'qux',
       'c' => 'quux',
       'd' => 'corge'
   ),
   array(
       'a' => 'grault',
       'b' => 'garply',
       'e' => 'waldo'
   ),
);

$foo = array_column($mismatchedColumns, 'a', 'b');
```

Results in `$foo` equal to:

```
Array
(
   [bar] => foo
   [0] => qux
   [garply] => grault
)
```

Essentially, the value at **a** becomes the new array value, and **b** becomes the key. When the original array does not contain the key **b**, it creates a 0 index and uses that instead. If there were multiple keys that did not exist, they would be incremental from 0.

Looking into their examples a little further, it hints that when you are unable to match a value in the the original array, you won't get an array element at all. This means if you were looking for a single value in an array and it didn't exist, it would return an empty array.

---

P.S. I've obviously never **used** this function, so most of this is interpretation of the RFC.

---

On a side note, this function was accepted for inclusion in PHP and was originally proposed by Ben Ramsey with a final result from voting of 38 in favor and 6 against. The mailing list discussion can be viewed here: http://grokbase.com/t/php/php-internals/126nxxa80p/draft-rfc-array-column-function. See also https://github.com/php/php-src/pull/257

Comment: I'm not following. Can you give an example?

Comment: Your example isn't quite the the same as the OPs.

Comment: @RocketHazmat: I removed the part where it showed how a similar array would look if initialized as such.